# Calculate balance per each category group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `my_table` which contains groups of categories, each category has initial budget (`original_budget`):

[image]

I am trying to add a new column `balance` so it contains the balance after reducing `expense` from the `original_budget` in each category group. Something like:

[image]

my try:

```
SELECT category, expense, original_budget, (original_budget-expense) AS balance
FROM my_table GROUP BY category order by `trans_date`
```

> MySQL version: innodb_version 5.7.25
>   10.2.23-MariaDB

Comment: remove group by category

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Your data set is missing a fourth column which would provide for the _ordering_ in which the transactions happened.  Without that, we can't give you an exact answer.

Comment: i think you need something like this: `SELECT category
   , sum(expense) as expense
   , sum(original_budget) as original_budget
   , sum(original_budget-expense) AS balance
from my_table
group by category`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If I understood you well, I have updated the question based on your comment.

Comment: @Aan, can you give us `insert statements` for sample data instead of image. It would really help.

Comment: @JitendraYadav Feel free to poach my demo `:-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then it is fairly straightforward to use `SUM` here as a window function:

```
SELECT
    trans_date,
    category,
    expense,
    original_budget,
    original_budget - SUM(expense) OVER
        (PARTITION BY category
         ORDER BY trans_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) balance
FROM my_table
ORDER BY
    category,
    trans_date;
```

[image]

### Demo

On earlier versions of MySQL, we can try to compute the rolling balance using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT
    trans_date,
    category,
    expense,
    original_budget,
    original_budget - (SELECT SUM(t2.expense) FROM my_table t2
                       WHERE t1.category = t2.category AND
                             t2.trans_date <= t1.trans_date) balance
FROM my_table t1
ORDER BY
    category,
    trans_date;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

**For All MySQL versions**:

You can use [MySQL User defined Variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) to reduce balance amount for a category. For this keep same category records together with sorted dates.

```
SELECT 
    category, 
    expense, 
    original_budget, 
    IF(@cat <> category, @budg:= original_budget - expense, @budg:= @budg - expense) AS balance,
    @cat:= category -- Set category to current value so we can compare it in next iteration
FROM my_table,
(SELECT @cat:= '' AS c, @budg:= NULL AS b) AS t
ORDER BY category, `trans_date`;


Output:
| category   | expense   | original_budget   | balance   | @cat:= category   |
| A          | 10        | 100               | 90        | A                 |
| A          | 2         | 100               | 88        | A                 |
| A          | 1         | 100               | 87        | A                 |
| B          | 12        | 300               | 288       | B                 |
| B          | 1         | 300               | 287       | B                 |
| B          | 1         | 300               | 286       | B                 |
| B          | 1         | 300               | 285       | B                 |
```

Comment: It is simple concept, a varible which holds balance value. Whenever category changes it will set to `initial balance - expense` orherwise reduces expense only.